# Подскажите какой-нибудь способ для обработки видео в c#

Tags: c#, .net, видео

Задача такая: загрузить изображение или видео ( .avi .mp4 .webm ) через интерфейс .NET в c# и после этого иметь возможность производить попиксельные манипуляции, а затем сохранять. С изображениями я справился, благо в .net есть для этого инструменты типо picture box, а вот как быть с видео не знаю. Посоветуйте пожалуйста какую-нибудь библиотеку (или может какой-нибудь другой способ) для попиксельного взаимодействия с каждым кадром видео с#

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/FFMpegCore например